# If / else statement in for loop

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I have a for loop that gathers locations from the Firebase Database. From this data I also calculate a distance between the users phone and the location it self.

My app now breaks if the userData is not found, so I would like to create a failsafe for if the user location isn't there. However I am not able to get this to work...both the console.log entries from the if AND else statement aren't fired. I also don't see the Does this work outside comment. It's late for me so maybe I'm missing something obvious?

```js
for (const key in resData) {
    const reduxUserLocation = getState().locationActions.userLocation

    if (reduxUserLocation === null) {
    const calculateDistance = getDistance(
        { latitude: resData[key].location[0].lat, longitude: resData[key].location[0].lng },
        { latitude: reduxUserLocation.lat, longitude: reduxUserLocation.lng }
    )
    console.log('distance?' , calculateDistance)

    loadLocations.push(
        new ReportedLocations(
            key,
            resData[key].ownerId,
            resData[key].location,
            resData[key].description,
            resData[key].streetname,
            resData[key].placename,
            resData[key].date,
            calculateDistance
        )
    );
        }
        else {
            console.log("user location isn't found")
            const calculateDistance = 0

            loadLocations.push(
                new ReportedLocations(
                    key,
                    resData[key].ownerId,
                    resData[key].location,
                    resData[key].description,
                    resData[key].streetname,
                    resData[key].placename,
                    resData[key].date,
                    calculateDistance
                )
            );        
        }
        console.log('Does this work outside the if/else statement?')
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error, change single quotes per double quotes around "console.log('user location isn't found')" and it should work

Comment: Dang see, it was late for me I missed those ;-) Didn't fix the problem but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears you are trying to retrieve a lat/long value from reduxUserLocation when it is null

```
if (reduxUserLocation === null) {
    const calculateDistance = getDistance(
        { latitude: resData[key].location[0].lat, longitude: resData[key].location[0].lng },
        { latitude: reduxUserLocation.lat, longitude: reduxUserLocation.lng } // THIS LINE
    )
```

Obviously this is not possible and it would throw an error. Therefor, you are not seeing any log lines below it.

Furthermore, I believe your if-statement is incorrect. It seems like you want to calculate the distance if possible and else it should be 0. Your if-statement does the reverse.

Besides that, there is a catch when using a for-in loop. Best to always check if hasOwnProperty

> If you only want to consider properties attached to the object itself, and not its prototypes, use getOwnPropertyNames() or perform a hasOwnProperty() check (propertyIsEnumerable() can also be used). Alternatively, if you know there won't be any outside code interference, you can extend built-in prototypes with a check method.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Here is, what I believe should be the correct code

```
for (const key in resData) {
  // Check if key is a property, if not, skip this iteration
  if (!resData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    continue;
  }

  const reduxUserLocation = getState().locationActions.userLocation;

  let calculateDistance = 0; // Set default distances to 0

  // If location is present, use that to calculate the distance and overwrite the variable above
  if (reduxUserLocation){
    calculateDistance = getDistance(
      {latitude: resData[key].location[0].lat, longitude: resData[key].location[0].lng},
      {latitude: reduxUserLocation.lat, longitude: reduxUserLocation.lng}
    );
  }
 
  // Moved push to array after the if-statement -> DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)
  loadLocations.push(
    new ReportedLocations(
      key,
      resData[key].ownerId,
      resData[key].location,
      resData[key].description,
      resData[key].streetname,
      resData[key].placename,
      resData[key].date,
      calculateDistance
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: You are a life saver Max! My code now works as expected thank you very much!! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to debug without seeing the code you use for the firestore query. If I had to guess I would look into checking for empty documents/queries using calls to the SDK as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data). I customized the example code in the docs based on your code.

Here's some code for a single document read.

```js
let resData;
const doc = await cityRef.get();
if (!doc.exists) {
  console.log('No such document!');
  resData = null
} else {
  resData = doc.data();
}
```

and a collection

```js
let resDataArr = []
const snapshot = await citiesRef.where('capital', '==', true).get();
if (snapshot.empty) {
  console.log('No matching documents.');
  resDataArr = [null]
} else {
  snapshot.forEach(doc=> resDataArr.push(doc.data()) );
}
```

This may change if you're using a library. I didn't test this code so there may be a syntax error or two.

Comment: The problem isn't with the Firebase query. The resData is filled and has every information from Firebase to calculate the distance. The problem lies within the reduxUserLocation that is empty (Because a user didn't give rights on fetching the location).

Because reduxUserLocation is null, the calculateDistance throws the error. So I want if reduxUserLocation is set calculate Distance, if not just set a distance of zero everywhere. 

Somehow the if/else statement is completely ignored in my code.